# C*-Algebra: Cyclic Elements

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Given a locally compact Hausdorff space $\Omega$.

Consider the C*-algebra:
$$\mathcal{C}_\infty(\Omega):=\left\{\varphi\in\mathcal{C}(\Omega):\|\varphi\|_{K^\complement}\stackrel{K\to\infty}{\to}\infty\right\}$$

Generated C^*-Algebra:
$$\mathcal{A}(\chi):=\overline{\bigg\{p(\chi,\chi^*):p\in\mathbb{C}[X,X^*]\bigg\}}$$

It admits cyclic elements:
$$\chi\in\mathcal{C}_\infty(\Omega):\quad\mathcal{A}(\chi)=\mathcal{C}_\infty(\Omega)$$

I don't think so, or? *(Example?)*

Comment: Took me a while to decipher the notation. What you call $C_\infty(\Omega)$ is what's usually known as the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity, or $C_0(\Omega)$. And I had no idea what you were talking about with $\mathcal A$ for a while - you meant "For $\chi\in C_\infty(\Omega)$ consider the $C^*$ algebra generated by $\chi$: [definition]."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general. If there exists $\chi\in C_\infty(\Omega)$ such that $\chi$ is injective then Stone-Weierstrass implies that $\mathcal A(\chi)=C_\infty(\Omega)$.

But for "most" $\Omega$ there is no such $\chi$, and if $\chi$ is not injective it's clear that $\chi$ does not generate $C_\infty(\Omega)$: If $\chi(a)=\chi(b)$ then $f(a)=f(b)$ for all $f\in\mathcal A(\chi)$, hence $\mathcal A(\chi)\ne C_\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: So would the circle constitute a counterexample?

Comment: The circle is one of the special $\Omega$ for which there does exist a cyclic vector, yes.

Comment: Did you meant "for which there does exist *no* cyclic vector"?

Comment: ??? We've seen that a function in our space is cyclic if and only if it is injective. There is a continuous injective function from the circle to $\Bbb C$. It's given by $\chi(z)=z$.

Comment: Ah I forget that it may have complex values...

Comment: What would be a counterexample then?

Comment: Seems clear to me that, for example, any open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ for $n>2$ gives a counterexample. But don't ask me to prove that, I suspect it may require more topology than I know (maybe not).

Comment: Ah yes intuitively that seems to work. Thank you!!